# Making the image upload work with imperavi redactor and symfony

Tags: php, image, symfony, upload, redactor

I'm currently coding a symfony app, and i'm having trouble with the Imperavi Redactor image upload.

Redactor loads fine for texteareas in my usual forms all over the website, but i can't make the uploading work.

I call Redactor in my "base.html.twig" with this code :

### base.html

> $('.redactor').redactor({
>
> > plugins: ['fullscreen'],
> >     });

This code works fine to load and edit the text. It works as well to use internet images, but i want to use the live upload setting that made me choose this editor. And the docs ask me to add a

> imageUpload : "/image/upload.php"

But as i'm using symfony i have a :

> imageUpload : Routing.generate('bdl_appli_appli_imageupload')

That should work fine. (js-routing works fine elsewhere in the website)
I then added the code from the website in my controller:

> public function imageUploadAction() {
>
> $dir = 'C:/wamp/www/bdl-capital/web/upload/images/';
>
> $_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);
>
> if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
>   || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
>   || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
>   || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
>   || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
>   {
>
> > ```
> > // setting file's mysterious name
> > ```
> >
> > $file = $dir.md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';
> >
> > // copying
> >        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);
> >
> > // displaying file
> >        $array = array(
> >            'filelink' => '/images/'.$file
> >         );
>
> ```
> $response = new JsonResponse();
> $return $response->setData($array);
> ```
>
> }

However, this does not work, and i'm looking for any advice.

I found this bundle : 
https://github.com/AStepanov/RedactorBundle

But it hasn't been updated for a year now, and i tried it without success, the redactorType is not updated to symfony 2.4... I tried to use the service alone but still no clue...

Has anyone managed to do this properly ? Can i use a pure PHP file within my symfony app just for this section ? I'm ready to have this tiny bit of code in pure php but i really have to make it work...

Comment: Please i realy need some help.. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone trying to get to the same result, i managed to find an updated version of the bundle :
https://github.com/kraksoft/RedactorBundle/network

I made my own version based on it and even managed to make the copy&paste from clipboard work, and will try to update my own bundle at the beginning of summer here :
https://github.com/florentdestremau/RedactorBundle
Feel free to ask for it if you need it now